# Is there a way for me to send a GET/POST request to my public_html folder in cPanel?

Tags: javascript, fetch, cpanel

I'm trying to access a resource I need for my website. Everything is stocked in cPanel.

The file permissions for my "public_html" folder are 750, and the permissions for the file I want to access are 644. In theory, I should be able to write the following GET request : `https://myWebsite.net/foo.bar` and it would return the resource I'm asking for.

Unfortunately, this is not the case, and the page that gets brought up is a `LiteSpeed Web Server` 403 Forbidden page, with the following error message : `Access to this resource on the server is denied!`

Alternatively, I'm trying to execute the following fetch command, in Javascript :

`var url = "https://myWebsite.net/foo.geoJson"
d3.geoJson(url, function(data){
//my code here
})`

But that doesn't work either. Is there something I can do to fix this ? Are my permissions wrong ? Do I need to use a username/password along with my fetch request ?

Comment: You probably have a .htaccess file that is controlling access permissions to certain resources

Comment: I do, it's the Joomla! auto-generated .htaccess file : https://docs.joomla.org/Preconfigured_htaccess. I'm not sure whether that's the thing stopping me from making a simple fetch request, though

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it :

It seems that I wasn't catering for json files in my .htaccess file.